# how to post headers with axios in react

Tags: reactjs, laravel, post, axios, token

Hi i have this problem: 
i made and API with an auth JWT runs perfect and my front is in react so i need only one component its a simple app, so in my App.jsx  i have my axios post to get the token and then i pass my token through the component, then i receive the props in the component and i saw the token but when i pass to the header like i test in postman, so nothing happens, and if i try the front and in the API i disable the JWT in my route works perfectly so i let my code next

```
const Cards = (props) => {

 //console.log(props.auth.token);
    //axios connection
    const apiCall = async () =>{
      let config = {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${props.auth.token}`
        }
      }
      console.log(config);
    try {
      const res = await clientAxios.post('/api/games', config,
      {
       console: 'nintendo',
       game: 'super mario',
       duration: '60hs'
      },)
      console.log(props.auth.token);
     } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.status);
     }

    }


  apiCall();
```

Comment: And if i put console.log  to the config works fine and the token its the right one

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the token with each request, set the token in axios' default headers like so:

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${jwtToken}`;
```

Comment: thanks i all ready fix the problem was in how i wrote the axios.post like this
clientAxios.post('/api/games', config, data) but its wrong cause i need to pass the config part in last like this
clientAxios.post('/api/games',data, config)